# Sort array with special character javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following array. How can I sort it properly? I tried the following:

```
var array = ["1000:2", "101:234", "102", "101:11", "11", "12"];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return  a.localeCompare(b)
})
console.log(array)
```

But its not giving the correct output. After sorting it should produce: 11, 12, 101:11, 101:234, 102, 1000:2. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `parseInt` on the arguments, which will take only the initial numeric part of the argument (dropping the `:` and anything past it, if it exists):

```js
var array = ["1000:2", "101:234", "102", "11", "12"];
array.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b))
console.log(array)
```

If you were intending to treat the `.` like a decimal, then replace the `:` with a `.`, then subtract to find the difference:

```js
var array = ["1000:2", "101:234", "102", "11", "12"];
array.sort((a, b) => a.replace(':', '.') - b.replace(':', '.'))
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to treat the : as a . in this case.